# Skype Call recording

Tags: skype, skypedeveloper, skype4com, skype-bots, skype4py

I want to record skype calls with the help of any skype client/module. I searched a lot on all forums but all solutions are outdated and mostly don't work. I want to  make my code flexible in such a way that it can automatically detect ongoing call and then record and save in a specified directory.
Can anyone please help me out?

P.S. - I would prefer Python implementation if possible

Thanks

Comment: have you found any solution. I have the same problem.

Comment: not yet @devedv ....  :-(